Importing product from XML into Woocommerce no variations or attributes are assigning
I'm trying to import products from XML feed using the below code. The products are being created (simple & variable), the attributes are being created, however, they are not assigned to the created products. Although in the debugging log it shows all attributes, terms were assigned.
function import_woocommerce_product($product_xml) {
    $sku = (string)$product_xml->reference;

    if (empty($sku)) {
        error_log("Skipping product: Missing SKU.");
        return;
    }

    if (wc_get_product_id_by_sku($sku)) {
        error_log("Product with SKU $sku already exists. Skipping.");
        return;
    }

    $product_type = isset($product_xml->attributes) && $product_xml->attributes->children() ? 'variable' : 'simple';
    $product_obj = $product_type === 'variable' ? new WC_Product_Variable() : new WC_Product_Simple();

    $product_obj->set_name((string)$product_xml->name);
    $product_obj->set_sku($sku);
    $product_obj->set_regular_price((float)$product_xml->price);
    $product_obj->set_description((string)$product_xml->description_short);
    $product_obj->set_status('publish'); // Automatically publish the product

    // Save product first to get an ID
    $product_obj->save();
    error_log("New $product_type product created: SKU $sku with Product ID " . $product_obj->get_id());

    if ($product_type === 'variable') {
        assign_product_attributes_and_create_variations($product_obj, $product_xml->attributes);
        $product_obj->save(); // It's crucial to re-save the product after setting attributes and creating variations
    }
}

function assign_product_attributes_and_create_variations($product_obj, $attributes_xml) {
    if (empty($attributes_xml) || !$attributes_xml->children()) {
        error_log("No attributes provided for variation creation.");
        return;
    }

    $attributes = array();
    $attribute_data = array();

    foreach ($attributes_xml->children() as $attr_xml) {
        $group_name = urldecode((string)$attr_xml->group_name);
        $attribute_name = sanitize_text_field((string)$attr_xml->attribute_name);

        error_log("Processing attribute: Group = $group_name, Attribute = $attribute_name");

        $taxonomy = ensure_attribute_exists($group_name);
        if (!$taxonomy) {
            error_log("Failed to register taxonomy for: $group_name");
            continue;
        }

        $term_id = ensure_term_exists($attribute_name, $taxonomy);
        if (!$term_id) {
            error_log("Failed to ensure term exists: $attribute_name in taxonomy $taxonomy");
            continue;
        }

        wp_set_object_terms($product_obj->get_id(), [(int)$term_id], $taxonomy, true);
        error_log("Assigned term $attribute_name (ID: $term_id) to product $group_name");

        $attributes[$taxonomy][] = $term_id; // Collect term ids for each attribute

        $attribute_data[$taxonomy] = array(
            'name'         => wc_attribute_label($taxonomy),
            'value'        => '',
            'is_visible'   => 1,
            'is_variation' => 1,
            'is_taxonomy'  => 1
        );
    }

    // Assign attributes to the product
    if (!empty($attribute_data)) {
        $product_obj->set_attributes($attribute_data);
    }

    // Mark attributes for use in variations
    update_post_meta($product_obj->get_id(), '_product_attributes', $attribute_data);

    // Create variations based on attributes
    foreach ($attributes as $attr_key => $term_ids) {
        foreach ($term_ids as $term_id) {
            $variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
            $variation->set_parent_id($product_obj->get_id());
            $variation->set_attributes(array($attr_key => get_term_by('id', $term_id, $attr_key)->slug));
            $variation->set_regular_price($product_obj->get_regular_price());
            $variation->set_stock_quantity(10);
            $variation->set_manage_stock(true);
            $variation->set_stock_status('instock');
            $variation->save();

            error_log("Created variation with attribute $attr_key term ID $term_id for product ID " . $product_obj->get_id());
        }
    }

    // Save the product again after creating variations
    $product_obj->save();
}

function ensure_attribute_exists($attribute_name) {
    global $wpdb;
    $attribute_name = urldecode($attribute_name);
    $taxonomy = 'pa_' . wc_sanitize_taxonomy_name($attribute_name);

    if (!taxonomy_exists($taxonomy)) {
        $result = wc_create_attribute(array(
            'name' => $attribute_name,
            'slug' => sanitize_title($attribute_name),
            'type' => 'select',
            'order_by' => 'menu_order',
            'has_archives' => false,
        ));

        if (is_wp_error($result)) {
            error_log('Failed to create attribute: ' . $result->get_error_message());
            return false;
        }

        delete_transient('wc_attribute_taxonomies');

        register_taxonomy(
            $taxonomy,
            'product',
            array(
                'label' => $attribute_name,
                'public' => true,
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'query_var' => true,
                'rewrite' => false,
            )
        );
    }

    return $taxonomy;
}

function ensure_term_exists($term_name, $taxonomy) {
    $term_name = urldecode($term_name);
    $term = term_exists($term_name, $taxonomy);
    if (!$term) {
        $inserted_term = wp_insert_term($term_name, $taxonomy);
        if (is_wp_error($inserted_term)) {
            error_log('Failed to insert term: ' . $inserted_term->get_error_message());
            return false;
        }
        return (int)$inserted_term['term_id'];
    }
    return (int)$term['term_id'];
}

Here is the log from the debug file:
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] New variable product created: SKU 103375942 with Product ID 31207
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Processing attribute: Group = اللون, Attribute = عسلي
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Assigned term عسلي (ID: 454) to product اللون
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Processing attribute: Group = اللون, Attribute = عسلي
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Assigned term عسلي (ID: 454) to product اللون
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Processing attribute: Group = اللون, Attribute = عسلي
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Assigned term عسلي (ID: 454) to product اللون
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Processing attribute: Group = اللون, Attribute = عسلي
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Assigned term عسلي (ID: 454) to product اللون
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Processing attribute: Group = اللون, Attribute = عسلي
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Assigned term عسلي (ID: 454) to product اللون
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Processing attribute: Group = اللون, Attribute = عسلي
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Assigned term عسلي (ID: 454) to product اللون
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Processing attribute: Group = اللون, Attribute = عسلي
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Assigned term عسلي (ID: 454) to product اللون
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Processing attribute: Group = اللون, Attribute = عسلي
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Assigned term عسلي (ID: 454) to product اللون
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Processing attribute: Group = القياس, Attribute = 40
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Assigned term 40 (ID: 406) to product القياس
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Processing attribute: Group = القياس, Attribute = 41
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Assigned term 41 (ID: 408) to product القياس
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Processing attribute: Group = القياس, Attribute = 42
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Assigned term 42 (ID: 448) to product القياس
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Processing attribute: Group = القياس, Attribute = 43
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Assigned term 43 (ID: 449) to product القياس
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Processing attribute: Group = القياس, Attribute = 44
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Assigned term 44 (ID: 450) to product القياس
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Processing attribute: Group = القياس, Attribute = 45
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Assigned term 45 (ID: 451) to product القياس
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Processing attribute: Group = القياس, Attribute = 46
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Assigned term 46 (ID: 452) to product القياس
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Processing attribute: Group = القياس, Attribute = 47
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Assigned term 47 (ID: 453) to product القياس
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Created variation with attribute pa_اللون term ID 454 for product ID 31207
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Created variation with attribute pa_اللون term ID 454 for product ID 31207
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:23 UTC] Created variation with attribute pa_اللون term ID 454 for product ID 31207
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:24 UTC] Created variation with attribute pa_اللون term ID 454 for product ID 31207
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:24 UTC] Created variation with attribute pa_اللون term ID 454 for product ID 31207
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:24 UTC] Created variation with attribute pa_اللون term ID 454 for product ID 31207
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:24 UTC] Created variation with attribute pa_اللون term ID 454 for product ID 31207
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:24 UTC] Created variation with attribute pa_اللون term ID 454 for product ID 31207
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:24 UTC] Created variation with attribute pa_القياس term ID 406 for product ID 31207
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:24 UTC] Created variation with attribute pa_القياس term ID 408 for product ID 31207
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:24 UTC] Created variation with attribute pa_القياس term ID 448 for product ID 31207
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:24 UTC] Created variation with attribute pa_القياس term ID 449 for product ID 31207
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:24 UTC] Created variation with attribute pa_القياس term ID 450 for product ID 31207
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:24 UTC] Created variation with attribute pa_القياس term ID 451 for product ID 31207
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:24 UTC] Created variation with attribute pa_القياس term ID 452 for product ID 31207
[20-Dec-2024 23:32:24 UTC] Created variation with attribute pa_القياس term ID 453 for product ID 31207

I'm not sure what I'm missing?! Thank you in advance!
I tried to reconfigure the code multible times with no luck
